# 3 boxes inline, content alignment

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 boxes with dynamic content, in each box there is a form with submit button, and some other things. How to get the effect from the picture.

Height of the each box is max from all boxes. Submit buttons in one line, on the bottom. [image]

```css
body {
  width: 720px;
}
form input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
form label {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.box-container {
  display: flex;
}
.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: calc(33% - 2px);
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla bla</h1>
    <p> some information dasd asd asd asdasdasfs dsgd dfg sdfg fsdg sdfg s</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla bladada das dasd asd</h1>
    <p>Longer information<br> some information dasd asd asd asd an</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <label>value 3</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla b</h1>
    <p>Longer information</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: have fix height for form and position the button at bottom.. this does not need jquery but css only i will update the tags

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Ok. Thanks to all of you for the answers. I resolved my problem.

```css
form input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

form label {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}
.box form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
}
.box p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <form>
      <div class="top">
      <h1>bla bla bla</h1>
      <p> some information dasd asd asd asdasdasfs dsgd dfg sdfg fsdg sdfg s</p>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <form>
      <div class="top">
        <h1>bla bla bladada das dasd asd</h1>
        <p>Longer information<br> some information dasd asd asd asd an</p>
        <label>value 1</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <label>value 2</label>
        <input type="text" />
        <label>value 3</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
     <div class="bottom">
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
     </div>
     </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <form>
      <div class="top">
        <h1>bla bla b</h1>
        <p>Longer information</p>
        <label>value 1</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote something from scratch for you to  use as base.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper > div {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 830px;
}

.wrapper > div > input[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 25px;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
}

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```

At the end, it looks something like this. I added `.clearfix` just in case you'll add more content after it.

[image]

Play around with it [here](https://codepen.io/joaquintoral/pen/VWLwzb). Hopefully, this can help you out.

Also, if you don't like the idea of using position absolute. I did it this way just to demonstrate how it will look like, without the dummy contents above the buttons.

An alternative is to create a wrapper for each of those rectangular nodes. Inside the wrapper, declare two divs that overlap each other. The bottom div should contain the submit button.

Comment: My forms don't  have fixed dimensions (height)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you needed. I have added flex property to the form to take all the space available

```css
body {
  width: 720px;
}

form {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

form input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

form label {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

form button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.box-container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  max-width: calc(33% - 2px);
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box p {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1>bla bla bla</h1>
      <p> some information dasd asd asd asdasdasfs dsgd dfg sdfg fsdg sdfg s</p>
    </div>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla bladada das dasd asd</h1>
    <p>Longer information<br> some information dasd asd asd asd an</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>value 3</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla b</h1>
    <p>Longer information</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-direction: column;` to the heading, content and form  and put `justify-content: flex-end` to form and it will fix the issue

```
.box h1,
.box p,
.box form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}
.box form {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```css
form input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}

form label {
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.box-container {
    display: flex;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    max-width: calc(33% - 2px);
    text-align: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box p {
    text-align: justify;
}

.box h1,
.box p,
.box form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
}

.box form {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla bla</h1>
    <p> some information dasd asd asd asdasdasfs dsgd dfg sdfg fsdg sdfg s</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla bladada das dasd asd</h1>
    <p>Longer information
      <br> some information dasd asd asd asd an</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <label>value 3</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla b</h1>
    <p>Longer information</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added some left margin to the 2nd and 3rd columns for the spacing. I have absolute bottom positioned a new button wrapper with padding to centrally position it. I have added some padding bottom on the box to help prevent the button overlapping the content. This would run in to issue if the button got bigger or the button text wrapped on to another line, however it is the best solution I could think of.

```css
form input {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}
form label {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}
.box {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 33.333%;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 10px 40px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.box:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.box p {
  text-align: justify;
}
.button-wrap  {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  padding:10px;
}
.button-wrap input {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla bla</h1>
    <p> some information dasd asd asd asdasdasfs dsgd dfg sdfg fsdg sdfg s</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text"/>
   <div class="button-wrap">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
   </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla bladada das dasd asd</h1>
    <p>Longer information<br> some information dasd asd asd asd an</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <label>value 2</label>
      <input type="text"/>
      <label>value 3</label>
      <input type="text"/>
   <div class="button-wrap">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
   </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h1>bla bla b</h1>
    <p>Longer information</p>
    <form>
      <label>value 1</label>
      <input type="text"/>
   <div class="button-wrap">
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
   </div>
    </form>
  </div>
<div>
```